# Can I send Database between users?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF app. I need to do something so that users can share their databases localy (without internet). For example: "User-1 launch the app and adding some information to DB, after that user-1 downloads his DB to USB and gives it to user-2. User-2 succesfuly put DB from user-1 USB and easily launchs it with the same app on his PC". Can this be achived with EF/EF Core? Or what i need to use to achive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it sounds as a very bad practice, but maybe you have good reasons for this.

You could use LocalDB, which is an very small sql package which can read directly from the .mdf database file without having to 'setup a sql server';
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

Or like the user CodeCaster mentioned, use SQLLite. Which also reads and saves to a file locally;
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-tutorial/sqlite-export-csv/

Answer (score -2):

Entity Framework is a database-agnostic data access library. This means that it doesn't care where your database lives.

If you want a portable database, look into SQLite.